# Raising TypeError with typing.Literal

Tags: python, typeerror, literals, python-typing

I have a function that should only allow certain values for its input argument. If any other value is passed to the function I would like to raise a TypeError. I was trying to use typing.Literal for it, e.g. below example from https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/.

```
from typing import Literal

def accepts_only_four(x: Literal[4]) -> None:
    pass

accepts_only_four(4)   # OK
accepts_only_four(19)  # Rejected
```

I am expecting to see an error for `acceps_only_four(19)`, but I still receive a "pass".

Comment: Python has *no runtime type checking*.  Unless you write it yourself/use a library which implements it.  Type hints are for linters/ type checkers like mypy, which you run separately from the main code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with using @validate_arguments decorator from pydantic based on the comment.